# How to mathematically add ridge penalty to a loss function?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, regularization, loss-functions, ridge-regression

For this loss function:
$$L(w_1,w_2) = -6(0.1\cos(w_1) - w_1^2 - 0.5w_2^7 + \sin(w_2))e^{-w_1^2-w_2^2}$$

Assuming the X (features) and Y (target feature) are embedded within the coefficients, so you can ingnor them.

I want to add an $L2$ penalty:
$$\lambda \sum^m_{i=0} W_i^2$$

Since I have two parameters $w_1$ and $w_2$ do I add each one at a time? how would the formula look like?

something like this maybe?

$$L(w_1,w_2) = -6(0.1\cos(w_1) - w_1^2 - 0.5w_2^7 + \sin(w_2))e^{-w_1^2-w_2^2} + \lambda(w_1^2 + w_2^2) $$

I know it might be a trivial question but I just want to make sure I'm not doing a mistake.

Comment: yes that's right.  but why do you have such a weird cost function?

Comment: This doesn't have many characteristics of a loss function.  In particular, loss functions are generally used to assess the degree of closeness of their two arguments, and therefore had better be minimal when the arguments are equal.  That's not the case here.  Moreover, this $L$ isn't bounded either above or below, which is problematic for any kind of optimization application.

Comment: Do you know the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker theorem or how to use Lagrange multipliers in multivariable calculus?